# What does contentOffset do in a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

What is the use of the `contentOffset` property in `UIScrollView`?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

According to the **[documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)**, the `contentOffset` property represents:

> The point at which the origin of the
>   content view is offset from the origin
>   of the scroll view.

In plain speak, it's how far the view has moved in each direction (vertical and horizontal).  You can unpack vertical and horizontal distance by accessing the `x` and `y` properties of the `CGPoint`:

```
CGFloat xOffset = _myScrollView.contentOffset.x;
CGFloat yOffset = _myScrollView.contentOffset.y;
```

Comment: For example, if you wanted to present several (n) pages that could be scrolled through, you could create a UIScrollView with contentSize (n*pageWidth, pageHeight) and with frame size (pageWidth, pageHeight). You could then use contentOffset.x to determine (or set) which page was being (or should be) displayed.

Comment: Since scrolling is done by changing the bounds origin of the scroll view (or its content view? forget), is the contentOffset directly related to the bounds origin?

Answer (score 118):

It could be considered as the coordinate of the origin of `scrollView`'s frame relative to the origin of its `contentView`'s frame. See the picture below:

[image]

Comment: This is a much better answer. The selected answer is just a rehashing of the documentation.

Comment: However this does not seem to work, when I change the value of x it does nothing.

Comment: @Hugo I just described what it means, not how to get it to work correctly. Your problem may have various causes including where you are setting this property.

Comment: Superb answer I would say, explained clear and simple

Answer (score 14):

[image]

Here you see two rectangles:

- the visible area
- the total area

**Scrolling** is changing the origin of the visible area within the total area.

In iOS all views have a visible area represented by the `view.bounds` rectangle. The class `UIScrollView` is a view with an unique property: it has a second rectangle called “content view” with a size bigger than its bounds. Thus, in a scroll view:

- the visible area is `scrollView.bounds`
- the total area is called *content view*, whose size is `scrollView.contentSize`

`contentOffset` is another name for `scrollView.bounds.origin`, implemented as follows:

```
var contentOffset: CGPoint { 
    get { return bounds.origin }
    set {
        var bounds = self.bounds
        bounds.origin = newValue
        self.bounds = bounds
    }   
}
```

When we change the contentOffset programmatically, we are also changing the bounds.origin, which causes a different area of the content view to be rendered. If we animate this change with `setContentOffset(pt, animated: true)`, the scrollView appears to scroll as dragged by the user’s finger.

The official documentation defines contentOffset like this (italics are mine):

> [`contentOffset`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619404-contentoffset): The point at which the origin of the content view *(the total area)* is offset from the origin of the scroll view *(the visible area)*.

I’d like to highlight the comment of @westsider on the accepted answer:

> For instance, if you want to present n pages that can be scrolled through, you create a UIScrollView with contentSize (n*pageWidth, pageHeight) and with bounds size (pageWidth, pageHeight). You then set contentOffset.x = (n-1) * pageWidth with n = 1 to display the first page.