# Add Gesture Reconizer Outside UItableView Inside ContentOffSetView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have added content offset to my UITableView.

For better positioning of my Table and now, I would like to dismiss my UITableView When User taps on the Content Offset Part of My table view.

How can i add this?

Strictly i dont want to add anymore views above the table in my screen.

> Have done like Reference to the answer
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/39062209/5215474

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing exact code, I would do the following:

Add a UIGestureRecognizer to UITableView

Use a combination of scroll position and the point touched in screenspace to determine if a touch happened where you want.

Comment: It wont workout for me.. gesture is added only to the table substracting offset position