# ScrollView scrollToPosition programmaticaly

Tags: swift

i have a ViewController that containts View and One more View inside of it

Scroll works fine when i do it by my mouse, but if i use method scrollView.setContentOffset nothing happens.

I tried to check if scroll available using scrollView.delegate = works fine

UiViewController

```
class WishListViewController: UIViewController {

 private lazy var wishListHeaderView: WishListHeaderView = {
        let view = WishListHeaderView()
        view.delegate = self
        
        return view
    }()

}
```

UiView

```
class WishListHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {

private lazy var wishListNavigationView: WishListNavigationView = {
        let view = WishListNavigationView()
        view.delegate = self

        return view
    }()
 }
```

Current view with scroll, that is not working

```
private lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        
        return scrollView
    }()

private lazy var tabsStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.spacing = 8
        stackView.backgroundColor = PaletteApp.grayBackgroundButton
        
        return stackView
    }()

private func commonInit() {
        addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.left.right.top.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
            make.height.equalTo(38)
        }
        
        scrollView.addSubview(tabsStackView)
        tabsStackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
   }
.........
```

Here is method in this view, debagger shows that i am in this method. And after this if i use print i see scrollviewOffset (100, 0)

```
 func scrollToFirstTab() {
        self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0), animated: true)
    }
```

Where is a problem? Thank you

Comment: Where exactly do you call `scrollToFirstTab`? I didn't find it in your snippets.

Comment: UIViewController -> func scrollToFirstTab -> UIView -> func scrollToFirstTab -> UIView -> func scrollToFirstTab

Comment: I don't get what your comment is supposed to mean, but, once again, your code snippets don't show how and where you call the `scrollToFirstTab` method.

Comment: (1) I am seriously don't understand your comment, (2) I didn't ask for call chains, and (3) most importantly, I seriously don't understand rudeness of people who ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content offset is not the correct method, offset is the gap between content and scroll view itself. For more about content offset, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339798/what-does-contentoffset-do-in-a-uiscrollview/39062209#39062209).

You need to use `func scrollRectToVisible(CGRect, animated: Bool).`

`CGRect.zero` to scroll to top.